# Allegro PCB design: How to set referenced center during Footprint making

Tags: orcad, cadence, allegro

I have designed the Pads from Orcad Pad designer. Now I would like to make footprint of my IC but to design that i need a reference center point so that i can decide location of pins. Please tell if any other alternative is available to do so.
[image]
Please help in this regard.

Comment: The center point is just the handle by which you will place the IC, so it mainly affects editing. Typically this would be the exact center of the IC, so if you rotate the IC on the board, it doesn't shift around.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution. Actually the origin point was in mid of grid but it was in black colour so it was not visible. I go thorough Change colour option then on Drawing tab i changed the origin colour from the black to red. Now it is visible.